How to map real-world coordinates on 2d grid environment for simulation?
I am working on modeling an environment from real-world coordinates. So far, the project has been developed in Java and JASON (https://jason-lang.github.io/). Below is the code for modeling. I am facing an issue where I want to remove the overlapping of coordinates.
Result image:
As in the result, I have indicated red lines, those lines are I believe overlapped coordinates, which serve no purpose in the modeled environment as further a simulation will take place with agents on it.
package src.model;

import jason.environment.grid.GridWorldModel;
import jason.environment.grid.Location;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class AgentModel extends GridWorldModel {

    Logger log = Logger.getLogger(AgentModel.class.getName());

    public static final int WALL = 16;
    public static final int AGENTS = 2;

    private final Set<Location> wallLocation;
    private final Set<Location> processedLocations = new HashSet<>();
    private final int screenWidth;
    private final int screenHeight;
    private final double[][] coordinates;
    private final double[] minMax;
    private double lonScale;
    private double latScale;
    private double x0;
    private double y0;

    protected AgentModel(int gridWidth, int gridHeight, double[][] coordinates, double[] minMax) {
        super(gridWidth, gridHeight, WALL);
        this.coordinates = coordinates;
        this.screenWidth = gridWidth;
        this.screenHeight = gridHeight;
        this.minMax = minMax;
        this.wallLocation = new HashSet<>();

        initializeScaling();
        addWall();
        findEmptyCellsUntilWall();
    }

    private void initializeScaling() {
        double minLon = minMax[0];
        double maxLon = minMax[1];
        double minLat = minMax[2];
        double maxLat = minMax[3];

        double deltaLon = maxLon - minLon;
        double deltaLat = maxLat - minLat;

        if (deltaLon != 0.0 && deltaLat != 0.0) {
            lonScale = (screenWidth - 1) / deltaLon;
            latScale = (screenHeight - 1) / deltaLat;
            x0 = -minLon * lonScale;
            y0 = maxLat * latScale;

            if (lonScale > latScale) {
                lonScale = latScale;
                x0 = ((screenWidth - 1) - (minLon + maxLon) * lonScale) / 2.0;
            } else {
                latScale = lonScale;
                y0 = ((screenHeight - 1) + (minLat + maxLat) * latScale) / 2.0;
            }
        } else if (deltaLon != 0.0) {
            lonScale = (screenWidth - 1) / deltaLon;
            latScale = 0;
            x0 = -minLon * lonScale;
            y0 = (screenHeight - 1) / 2.0;
        } else if (deltaLat != 0.0) {
            lonScale = 0;
            latScale = (screenHeight - 1) / deltaLat;
            x0 = (screenWidth - 1) / 2.0;
            y0 = maxLat * latScale;
        } else {
            lonScale = 0;
            latScale = 0;
            x0 = (screenWidth - 1) / 2.0;
            y0 = (screenHeight - 1) / 2.0;
        }
    }

    private void addWall() {
        List<Location[]> coordinatePairs = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < coordinates.length - 1; i++) {
            Location start = transformCoordinates(coordinates[i][0], coordinates[i][1]);
            Location end = transformCoordinates(coordinates[i + 1][0], coordinates[i + 1][1]);
            coordinatePairs.add(new Location[]{start, end});
        }
        addWallsBetweenCoordinates(coordinatePairs);
    }

    private void addWallsBetweenCoordinates(List<Location[]> coordinates) {
        for (Location[] pair : coordinates) {
            if (pair.length < 2) continue;

            Location start = pair[0];
            Location end = pair[1];

            if (processedLocations.contains(start) && processedLocations.contains(end)) {
                continue;
            }

            addWallInBetween(start, end);
            processedLocations.add(start);
            processedLocations.add(end);
        }
    }

    private Location transformCoordinates(double x, double y) {
        int gridX = (int) (x0 + x * lonScale);
        int gridY = (int) (y0 - y * latScale);
        return new Location(gridX, gridY);
    }

    private void addWallInBetween(Location start, Location end) {
        int dx = Math.abs(end.x - start.x);
        int dy = Math.abs(end.y - start.y);
        int sx = start.x < end.x ? 1 : -1;
        int sy = start.y < end.y ? 1 : -1;
        int err = dx - dy;

        int x = start.x;
        int y = start.y;

        while (true) {
            Location loc = new Location(x, y);
            if (!wallLocation.contains(loc)) {
                wallLocation.add(loc);
                if (x >= 0 && x < getWidth() && y >= 0 && y < getHeight()) {
                    add(WALL, loc);
                }
            }
            if (x == end.x && y == end.y) {
                break;
            }
            int e2 = 2 * err;
            if (e2 > -dy) {
                err -= dy;
                x += sx;
            }
            if (e2 < dx) {
                err += dx;
                y += sy;
            }
        }
    }

    public void findEmptyCellsUntilWall() {
        for (int x = 0; x < getWidth(); x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < getHeight(); y++) {
                if (hasObject(WALL, x, y)) {
                    break;
                } else {
                    paintEmptyCells(x, y);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void paintEmptyCells(int startX, int startY) {
        for (int x = startX; x < getWidth(); x++) {
            if (hasObject(WALL, x, startY)) {
                break;
            } else {
                add(OBSTACLE, x, startY);
            }
        }

        for (int x = startX; x >= 0; x--) {
            if (hasObject(WALL, x, startY)) {
                break;
            } else {
                add(OBSTACLE, x, startY);
            }
        }

        for (int y = startY; y >= 0; y--) {
            if (hasObject(WALL, startX, y)) {
                break;
            } else {
                add(OBSTACLE, startX, y);
            }
        }

        for (int y = startY; y < getHeight(); y++) {
            if (hasObject(WALL, startX, y)) {
                break;
            } else {
                add(OBSTACLE, startX, y);
            }
        }
    }
}



I don't understand which specific problem you are facing. And what do you mean by "overlapping of coordinates"?

In 2D coordinates consist of only two numbers, which describe the easting and northing of a point. For two coordinates to overlap, I would think that they lie on the same easting and northing values, so they describe the same point in 2D space.
Maybe you mean you are facing problems with overlapping lines?

Thank you for your response. Yes, you are right, in my data I have some coordinates that are duplicated as I believe they are boundaries that set apart two objects and that is what causing the problem. The problem: From the image, I need to remove red highlighted lines.

What semantics do the coordinates have? Are they pairs where (p_i, p_i+1) describe a line?

Yes. i.e 31.888753711245954 31.75293996743858

Ok, and where do they come from? And how to decide which one of the colliding lines is the wrong one?

Yes, that is the issue. We can not identify which line is overlapping over which coordinates. I tried mapping each coordinate set (I am parsing from CityGML) individually with the condition of not placing a wall over an already placed wall. Worked well so far, but still need to check with other data.
